# Postgres/Postgis database - Query running infinitely with ST_MakeLine

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I currently have a database scheme called cardata, which amongst others have these columns:

```
+-------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
| tripid(int) | point geometry(point, 4326) | line geometry(linestring, 4326) |
+-------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1           | <data>                      |                                 |
| 1           | <data>                      |                                 |
```

The `point` column contains sequential GPS measurements, and as such I would like to transform them into linestrings. The whole trip can contain thousands of points, but I want a linestring between every single point.

I have tried to formulate this as an `update` to my table which looks like this:

```
UPDATE cardata
SET line = ST_MakeLine(foo.point, lead)
FROM (
    SELECT point, LEAD(point, 1)
    OVER w
    FROM cardata
    GROUP BY point
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY point)
) AS foo

WHERE lead IS NOT NULL
```

The idea is that for each row I use that point and the next to make a linestring (`ST_MakeLine`) saved in the first row (`line`). This should continue until the trip ends, ignoring the last entry in which `LEAD` should be null.

For now I do not know how to formulate a single query that distinguishes between different `tripid`, but that is for another time. For now I just want linestrings between all points in the entire table.

The problem is however that my query seems to run forever, and does not change anything in the table. I do not understand why. I tried testing that the inner `SELECT` query behaved as expected - It returns 46561 rows of 47055 total rows. This is also odd since I believe it should return 47054 rows - i.e. only conclude that for the last entry, `LEAD` is null.

Lastly I tried running the `ST_MakeLine` on two random points, which seems to work fine.

**What makes this query run forever?**

Comment: Do you have a column that marks the point's order within a trip? If not then the data is not recoverable.

Comment: I have id's for each entry log and also timestamps

Comment: Forgive me is I am being stupid but it looks to me like you are making 47000+ lines so that is going to be very slow. Your group by point isn't going to have any effect at all.

Comment: Making 47000+ lines was the idea, and it actually finishes quite fast, now that I have it running correctly. On my personal laptop the runtime is less than a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another guy that I am working with finally found a working solution, although neither of us quite understand what exactly was wrong with the original query.

As such I am still interested in the answer to my original question, namely **what made the query run forever?**

This is the working query, which works entirely as intended:

```
UPDATE cardata
    SET line = resline
    FROM(
        SELECT tripid,
               id,
               ST_MakeLine(point, next_point) AS resline
        FROM(
            SELECT tripid,
                   id,
                   point,
                   lead(point) OVER w AS next_point,
                   lead(tripid) OVER w AS next_tripid
            FROM cardata
            WINDOW w AS(ORDER BY id)
        ) AS allcalclines
        WHERE tripid = 1 AND next_tripid = tripid
    ) AS calclines
    WHERE cardata.id = calclines.id
```